# The page for the suggested edits shows me as the user who created a tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Looking at one of [suggested edits I have done for a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/811259), I noticed I am shown as creator of the tag wiki, which is not true, and it cannot happen, as I am not a 20K user on Stack Overflow.

[image: screenshot]

The creator is the Community user, as it happens in most of the cases. For that specific case, the [user who suggested the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6997397/revisions) was [Chase Florell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/124069/chase-florell). I have just suggested the latest edit, which was approved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an issue we fixed a while ago in code, but needed a data backfill which is rolling through the network now.

Originally when a post was suggested what happened was that community created an initial body for the tag wiki (and excerpt) that was empty then the suggested edit went into the queue.  That still happens.  What now *also* happens is if we see that case, we properly set the tag wiki owner to the suggester that really created the content.

What I *didn't* do is ever get around to fixing all the existing cases (18,887 on Stack Overflow)...that's now complete and you'll see the owner in [that suggested edit view](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/811259) is now correct.

Comment: Possibly related new bug report?
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294920/how-could-i-create-a-tag-wiki-three-years-before-i-joined-the-site