# How could I create a tag wiki three years before I joined the site?

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

While reviewing suggested edits, I came across [one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/103832) to a tag wiki which is listed as being created by me in 2011:

[image]

Just one problem: I joined Stack Exchange in 2014. **How can I have created anything on the site three years before I joined?**

Comment: Duplicate of [something that was fixed also before you joined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151405/307988) ...?

Comment: The reported duplicate is marked as "100% fixed"..

Comment: Time travel of information. May be an interesting topic on the Physics SE :-)

Comment: @Gnemlock doesn't strike me as implausible the data backfill didn't get run/complete for SF&F

Comment: @peterh Time travel is probably more on-topic on [scifi.se] than [physics.se] :-)

Comment: Science Fiction seems to drive science. Yesterday's magic is today's science fiction, tomorrow's science experiment, and next week's fact of life. I seem to recall some reports in particle physics of pre-event effects. That _could_ lead to time travel of information, as suggested by @peterh, without necessarily leading to actual, physical, time travel itself. The [science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape) version, the [science experiment](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms5145) version.