# Suggested edit says previous (documented, not missing) version of tag body was written by the current editor, but it wasn't

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Admittedly a very minor bug, perhaps even a one-time thing.

### The bug

[This suggested edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/139445) on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) states that user [Stormblessed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/102999/stormblessed) created the [stormlight-archive](/questions/tagged/stormlight-archive) tag's wiki on Feb 17th, 2016. Except their account didn't even exist until 5 months ago *(we SFF folks are open-minded about time travel, but still)*.

> [image: suggested edit displays wrong tag wiki creator]

[The tag body's history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/119739/revisions) shows that the tag was created by user [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor) (for [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/97282/revisions)) and documented shortly after:

> [image: tag history displays the right editors]

### The attempt at repro

- Doesn't seem to repro on excerpts. See [this edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/139440) by same user on SFF or [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77568) on M&TV.
- [I edited another tag body with no repro](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/139459). There are not a lot of tag bodies edits with the same setting; if I didn't miss anything in the review history, last one was [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/138935) (also no repro).

I'm posting that here instead of SFF Meta, as I think it could happen elsewhere on the network, but it's not something I can easily check (as SFF is the only site where I'm >10k and can access review history).

So what gives? Is it a one-time thing not to be bothered, with or is there a repro somewhere else?

### The search for a possible dupe

- [`[bug] [tag-wiki] [suggested-edits]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+tag-wiki+suggested-edits?sort=newest&pageSize=15) doesn't seem to yield anything (unless I missed one). Admittedly some questions might not be correctly tagged;
- "Similar Questions" algorithm suggests [The user who first proposed a tag wiki is treated as owner for suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168852/) - but in this case, editor was not the tag's creator, nor were they the one to write the wiki's previous version.

Comment: Admittedly though it's an old joke that I suck at Meta search so if anyone's got a dupe, sorry to have cluttered the homepage :)

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151405/377968) but shows status completed.

Comment: @AnneDaunted indeed. And there's even another linked question to that one (so I _do_ suck at Meta search :) ). Should we dupe-cose this? Although it's obviously not [status-completed]?

Comment: No, don't close it as a duplicate, since the bug still exists.

Comment: Here's another example: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/139064

Comment: [Here's a query to test for this condition (last editor owns wiki)](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/961680) - a quick scan suggests that the owner is either the creator, or - if Community creates the wiki - then the first person to *suggest* an edit.

Comment: @Shog9 so if I get that right, if the first wiki body is created by a >20k repper, they get stripped of ownership? :P

Comment: If the initial ownership is given to Community (because,say,someone just created an excerpt), then a mod or 20k user edits, *then* someone suggests an edit... The suggested editor not the first human editor will own the wiki.

Comment: @Shog9 I guess that's a (of minor importance) bug and not an intended treat for us peasants? :)

Comment: I have no idea why it works that way!

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294920/how-could-i-create-a-tag-wiki-three-years-before-i-joined-the-site, if not a duplicate.