# Single-use tags with no tag wiki, but with rejected proposals for the tag wiki, aren't auto-burninated after six months

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki, tag-pruning

Recently, there was some [confusion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325118/why-wasnt-this-tag-removed-despite-having-single-occurrence/325124#325124) as to why a single-use tag without a tag wiki wasn't auto-burninated after six months. It was later discovered that as someone made a [rejected proposal](https://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/96204) for the tag wiki, a blank wiki was automatically created by the Community user immediately upon edit submission, for technical reasons.

Tags with only one question are intended to be burninated after six months, *unless* they have a tag wiki (i.e. a community consensus as to what the tag actually represents). But since the proposed edit was rejected, there is effectively no consensus as to what the tag means, and should therefore be eligible for burnination. Also, a blank tag wiki created by the system for technical reasons is effectively the same as no tag wiki: the system even treats it as such since the notice on the tag info page that it has no wiki still continues to show up.

As such, tags only being used by one question with a rejected tag wiki proposal should be eligible for burnination. In other words, a single blank wiki created by the Community user shouldn't prevent it from being burninated.

Comment: It's not that big of a deal, and the premise still holds true. Someone cared enough to suggest an edit, regardless of whether it got rejected. And there's not really a *better* way to check if it has a tag wiki without making the query a lot more complicated, so I doubt anyone's gonna fix it to accommodate a super rare edge case...

Comment: Honestly, the real fix here is to re-examine the editing pipeline for suggested edits on tag wikis. The logic here is weird and [causes other problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321738/suggested-edit-says-previous-documented-not-missing-version-of-tag-body-was-w)

Answer (score 13):

Network wide there are today [only 307 of such tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1004134).

I don't think this bug needs immediate fixing but the query can be used to find tags that have no wiki but maybe deserve it.

Here is the multi-db query to get those results:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

create table #result (site sysname
                    , hostname sysname
                    , tagname nvarchar(150)
                    , wid integer
                    , eid integer)

select @sql = N'insert into #result' + STRING_AGG(concat(N'
select ''', name ,N''' as site
     , ''',hostname ,N'''
     , t.tagname
     , wikipostid
     , excerptpostid
from ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.tags t
left outer join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts pw on t.wikipostid = pw.id
left outer join ', quotename(name), N'.dbo.posts pe on t.excerptpostid = pe.id
where len(pe.body) = 0
and len(pw.body) = 0
and [count] = 1 
'),N' 
union all')
from (select convert(nvarchar(max),name) name
    -- , convert(nvarchar(max),sitename)  sitename
    -- , meta
    -- , domain
     ,  concat( 
        -- based on an idea from Glorfindel
        (case sitename
        WHEN 'Audio' THEN 'video'
        WHEN 'Beer' THEN 'alcohol'
        WHEN 'CogSci' THEN 'psychology'
        WHEN 'Garage' THEN 'mechanics'
        WHEN 'Health' THEN 'medicalsciences'
        WHEN 'Moderators' THEN 'communitybuilding'
        WHEN 'Photography' THEN 'photo'
        WHEN 'Programmers' THEN 'softwareengineering'
        WHEN 'Vegetarian' THEN 'vegetarianism'
        WHEN 'Writers' THEN 'writing'
        WHEN 'Br' THEN 'pt'
        WHEN 'Mathoverflow' THEN concat((meta+'.'), sitename)
        ELSE case when sitename = domain then null else sitename end
        end +'.')
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then (meta+'.') 
           else null 
           end) 
        , (case 
           when sitename <> 'mathoverflow' then concat((domain + '.'), 'com') 
           else 'net' 
           end)
        ) hostname
from (
select name
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then parsename(name,2)
  else parsename(name,1) 
  end [sitename]
, case parsename(name,1) 
  when 'Meta' then 'meta'
  else null
  end [meta]
  , coalesce(parsename(name,3), parsename(name,2)) [domain]
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
-- (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')
) dbs
) dbsall

exec (@sql)


select site
      , concat(N'https://', hostname, '/tags/', tagname, N'/info|', tagname) [single-use]

from #result
```

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.